# Cross domain access not working

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to make cross domain request to xml file. In `.htaccess` I have

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

and in `apache2/sites-available/default`

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

but I still receive the

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '*****' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edditing as follows, applying your paths:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

And make sure you have the right virtual hosts config you're editing. E.g. `apache2/sites-available/myVirtualWebsite.com`

Comment: This one worked for me, but there is one more important thing: mod_headers was not installed. http://harthur.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/configure-apache-to-accept-cross-site-xmlhttprequests-on-ubuntu/